# how to remove transformiix:result in firefox

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I am using xslt styelsheets to apply to xml, chrome and ie render correctly, however firefox seems to add xml tag

`transformiix:result`

How can i get this removed in firefox. It is affecting my javascript. I tried to do work around but its not working anymore

**workaround**

```
if($('body').length == 0){ // firefox is transforming xsl differently so this fix is needed
        var head = $("#top_section")
        var $set = $( document ).children();
        $set = $set.children();
        for(var i=1, len = $set.length; i < len; i +=5){
            $set.slice(i, i+6).wrapAll('<body />');
        }
    }
```

**update**

I am running php7 with apache.

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/xslt/user_services_owners.xsl"?>
<response>
  <header>
    <error>false</error>
    <message>success</message>
    <api_status>1</api_status>
    <api_response>success</api_response>
    <http_status>200</http_status>
    <http_response>ok</http_response>
    <format>xml</format>
    <csrf>946dc689cae6c5d0ae3fcf01de951493</csrf>
    <token>946dc689cae6c5d0ae3fcf01de951493</token>
    <user>UddinS2</user>
    <title>Manage Service, Project, Programme</title>
    <description>List, add, edit, and remove services, projects and programmes</description>
    <nav>
      <container>
        <title>Users</title>
        <link>#</link>
        <theme>#007c92</theme>
        <sub_modules>
          <title>Getting Started</title>
          <link>#</link>
          <theme>#007c92</theme>
          <menuitem>
            <title>File - CM Template v6.3</title>
            <link>/library/templates/FW-LB-CommsMatrix-Template-v6.3.xls</link>
          </menuitem>
          <menuitem>
            <title>Sudo Group Access</title>
            <link>/sudo_group_access.php?csrf=946dc689cae6c5d0ae3fcf01de951493</link>
          </menuitem>
        </sub_modules>
      </container>
    </nav>
    <server>1</server>
    <version>5.1</version>
  </header>
  <body>
    <recordset>
      <record>
        <ID>121</ID>
        <SERVICE_ID>201</SERVICE_ID>
        <NAME>UddinS2</NAME>
        <TYPE>owner</TYPE>
        <SERVICE>* Ad-hoc Submission</SERVICE>
      </record>
      <metadata>
        <num_rows>1</num_rows>
      </metadata>
    </recordset>
  </body>
</response>
```

**/xslt/user_services_owners.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:import href="header.xsl" />

    <!-- <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"  indent="no" media-type="text/html" />-->
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="iso-8859-1" media-type="html" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN" />

    <xsl:template match="body">

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- content of other element -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="footer" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**header.xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- header.xsl -->
    <xsl:template match="header">
        <!-- content of header -->
        <HEAD>
       </HEAD>

        <div class="container-fluid" id="top_section">
        </div>
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="hidden-print">
        </div>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div id="myModalError" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        </div>
</xsl:template>


    <xsl:template name="footer">
        <FOOTER>

        </FOOTER>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In firefox i see the below code after using my workaround.

```
<transformiix:result><head>....</head><body>....</body></transformiix:result>
```

I am using php to generate the xml which i put above which is echoed to browser. the browser translates the stylesheet and the workaround is triggered on `document.ready` only in firefox, which places the div's in the correct place inside body tag. without it there is no body tag. the problem is: jquery cannot locate body because it is encapsulated with transformiix in firefox

Comment: So which Javascript code do you use to run the XSLT in Firefox? Caonsider to add an executable code snippets that is minimal but complete to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XSLTProcessor you get that element if you use `transformToDocument` with `xsl:output method="text"`. Are you sure you want an XML document if your XSLT is supposed to produce plain text? It might be that `transformToFragment` better suits your needs. But simply show a minimal but complete and executable snippet to demonstrate the issue and I am sure we can help fixing it.

Comment: i have added code under udpate

Comment: You have added two XSLT snippets but no input XML and no Javascript code showing how you run the code.

Comment: i have added input xml

Comment: Have you tried to make sure that your XSLT create a well-formed and valid HTML result document by making sure you create a `html` root element with e.g. `<xsl:template match="/"><html><xsl:apply-templates/></html></xsl:template>`? I think in that case you will not get that `transformiix:result` added, as its only an attempt to put your various root less result elements into a single root element.

Comment: Im not sure how to do this. I have a header file which is being imported. Can you give me an example. Header.xsl contains head tag and nav content.

Comment: My comment had the suggestion, I have now put it into an answer as I don't think putting longer code snippets into a comment allows us to communicate well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current XSLT does not create a HTML root element so change your main stylesheet to e.g.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:import href="header.xsl" />


    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" doctype-system="about:legacy-doctype"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="body">

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- content of other element -->
        <xsl:apply-templates select="footer" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That should avoid the problem with the `transformiix:result` element being added. I think there are other issues with your approach that will not result in valid HTML but it is not as easy fixing them as you seem to want to output HTML result elements like `div` elements from different templates for the header and the body.

Comment: it is working now. so how would i check if i have valid xslt.

Comment: I just realised it removed the transformiix but the body tag is missing. in firefox

Comment: It is not the XSLT I referred to but the HTML created, if you want to validate the HTML then you can feed it to validator.w3.org, I don't think there is a way to do it directly in the browser, you would need to run the XSLT with an XSLT processor or editor outside of the browser so that you get an HTML file as the result you can then validate.

Comment: I don't think your XSLT creates a `body` element so that is one of the problems with the XSLT as structured and written so far, in other browsers the XSLT result is fed to the HTML parser which can correct and inject implicit or missing elements but that does not happen in Mozilla browsers.

Comment: problem i have is `header.xsl` contains `<head>` and some content of body and then there's the main stylesheets with body content